# How to compute the indefinite integral $\int \frac u{u+1}\,\mathrm du$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How do you compute $$ \int \frac{u}{u+1}\,\mathrm du$$

Comment: $$\frac u{u+1}=1-\frac1{u+1}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Ah! Partial fractions and integrals are old friends.:)

Comment: Can you show me the proof for that identity?

Comment: Using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html, $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}=A+\frac B{cx+d}$ Find $A,B$ by comparing the coefficients of the different powers of $x$

Comment: $$\frac{u}{u+1}=\frac{(u+1)-1}{u+1}=\frac{u+1}{u+1}-\frac{1}{u+1}=1-\frac{1}{u+1}.$$

Answer (score 8):

$$
\int \frac{u}{u+1} du = \int \frac{u+1-1}{u+1} du = \int 1 \, du - \int \frac{1}{u+1} du.
$$

Now it should be easy to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Integration by parts needlessly complicates this problem.

A simpler approach uses [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction).  Since
$$\frac{u}{u+1} = 1-\frac{1}{u+1},$$
we have
$$\int \frac{u}{u+1} du = \int 1du - \int \frac{1}{u+1}du = u - \log \vert u+1 \vert + c.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Integrate by parts.

$$\int\dfrac{u}{u+1}du=u \int\dfrac{1}{u+1}du-\int  \log(u+1)du$$

By the series of comments with Did,

$$\int \log u du= \log u\int1 du-\int u \cdot \dfrac{1}{u}du= (u\log u-u)$$

Comment: Please no. Finding a primitive of log(u+1) is certainly not easier than of u/(u+1). (Upvoter: can you explain your upvote?)

Comment: $\int \log (u)=u \log u-u+C$ as I have been taught.?

Comment: "thought" >> "taught". Sure, then what? You know by heart a primitive of log(u), you might also know by heart a primitive of u/(1+u)...

Comment: Inceptio that is correct

Comment: @Did: I 'thought' we are supposed to *know* the integrals of *known* standard functions.

Comment: I have no idea what it is you are talking about (define "known" function).

Comment: Inceptio: please stop modifying your comments after I answered them.

Comment: do note that you forgot to put what you're integrating with respect to in the answer - was confusing to me at first. @Did you can derive $\int \log u \, \mathrm{d} u$ by using integration by parts, right?

Comment: @Did: Sorry. I believe that you are right. I know how to derive the primitive of $\log x$. But the place where *I* have been thought, it's like people use primitive of $\log x$ like other standard functions($\sin x, \cos x)$.

Comment: @Did: I'm extremely sorry. *I* found it rather easy to have *integral* of $\log u$.

Answer (score 0):

integrate by parts using : $f = u$ and $g' = 1/ (1+u)$. this solves the problem